# Snap SVG repeat on hover slows on repeated hovers

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, snap.svg

Have a simple snap.svg rotate-on-hover animation.  Cog rotates on hover-in and stops on hover-out.

Works fine on the first hover in/out but on repeated hovers the animation slows (by half?) each time.  Have no idea why that would happen.

This is what i currently have:

```
<script> 
var cogs = Snap("#cogs");
var cog1 = cogs.select(".cog1");

cogs.hover(function cogs(){
cog1.stop().animate({ 'transform' : 'r-180,110,110' }, 5000, 
function(){ 
  cog1.attr({ transform: 'rotate(0 110 110)'});
})
cogs();
}, function() {
  cog1.stop(); 
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/hpz19wrc/

Comment: Think I've worked out why the animation slows on re-hover. 
When the animation stops and is then restarted the rotation needed complete animation in the time (5000) is less and therefor the speed slows.  Need to rethink how the animation works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just and TweenMax JS lib for advanced control, smooth motion, and performance!
https://jsfiddle.net/hpz19wrc/2/

```js
// 
var tl = new TimelineMax(),
 cogs = Snap("#cogs"),
 cog1 = cogs.select(".cog1");

// aniamtion
tl.to(".cog1", 5, {
 rotation: 360 , 
 repeat: -1, 
 transformOrigin: 'center',
 ease: Power0.easeNone
});

// control
tl.pause();
cogs.hover(function(){
  tl.resume();
}, function() {
  tl.pause();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.19.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>
<svg id="cogs" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
   viewBox="0 0 220 220" enable-background="new 0 0 220 220" xml:space="preserve" >
 <g class="cog1">
    <path id="cog1" fill="none" stroke="#000000" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M179.9475,103.2739L213,81.7477l-7.3875-18.618
 l-37.8643,6.8216c-3.722-5.378-8.088-10.1617-13.0059-14.2094l8.1445-38.559L144.496,9.2431l-21.9643,31.6172
 c-6.2764-1.1463-12.7157-1.4435-19.2115-0.8207L81.8017,7l-18.6173,7.3878l6.8143,37.8514
 c-5.3779,3.7221-10.1612,8.0813-14.216,12.9994L17.218,57.0937L9.2786,75.4851l31.616,21.9579
 c-1.1464,6.2767-1.4647,12.7233-0.8421,19.2194L7,138.1889l7.3874,18.6178l37.8643-6.8216
 c3.722,5.3781,8.0881,10.1617,13.006,14.2093l-8.1446,38.5592l18.3908,7.9396l21.9642-31.6171
 c6.2765,1.1463,12.7301,1.4789,19.2259,0.8561L138.2265,213l18.6245-7.3947l-6.8286-37.8797
 c5.3779-3.7222,10.1543-8.0955,14.209-13.0136l38.5577,8.1379l7.9395-18.3915l-31.6162-21.965
 C180.2588,116.2167,180.5773,109.763,179.9475,103.2739z M110,137.9208c-15.4735,0-28.0173-12.5442-28.0173-28.0183
 S94.5265,81.8842,110,81.8842s28.0173,12.5442,28.0173,28.0183S125.4735,137.9208,110,137.9208z"/>
  </g>
</svg>
```